# Terraform - How to update attribute for every single map in list of maps

Tags: terraform

I have the variable `mini_maps`. What is want to accomplish is to be able to update every `name` attribute containing lower case `x`, while using it in a `for`-loop.  E.g

```
locals {
  mini_maps = [
    {
      id = "1"
      name = "secret-x"
    },
    {
      id = "2"
      name = "tomz"
    },
    {
      id = "3"
      name = "juke-x"
    }
  ]

  levels = [ 1,2,3 ]

new_mini_maps = flatten([ for m in local.mini_maps :  # Update 'name' if contains lower case 'x'
                  for level in local.levels : regex('x', m.name) {  
                    id    = m.id
                    name  = "MAP_${replace(m.name, \"x\", \"X\")}" <-- Does not work !
                    difficulty = level
                  } : null
                ])
}
```

What I want to accomplish:

```
[
  {
    id = "1"
    name = "MAP_secret-X"
  },
  {
    id = "3"
    name = "MAP_juke-X"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `levels` array and its logic is unrelated to your question, so I will ignore it in my answer:

```
new_mini_maps = [
  for elm in local.mini_maps : {
    id   = elm.id
    name = "MAP_${replace(elm.name, "/-x$/", "-X")}"
  } if substr(elm.name, -2, -1) == "-x"
]
```

We want to filter out all elements which doesn't end with `-x`, so I'd use [`substr`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/substr) to compare the last 2 characters to `-x`:

```
if substr(elm.name, -2, -1) == "-x"
```

If this condition is met, we return the element with the `name` overridden with:

```
name = "MAP_${replace(elm.name, "/-x$/", "-X")}"
```

The patten `/-x$/` matches the last part of string `-x`, which prevents replacing the `x` in `alex` of:

```
{
  id   = "4"
  name = "alex-x"
}

# Output:
#
# + {
#   + id   = "4"
#   + name = "MAP_alex-X"
# },
```